# executing a click function without the user clicking?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function() {
    setInterval( "clickRight()", 5000 );
});

    $('.slide_right').click(function clickRight(){ 
etc...
```

I basically want my slideshow to move to the next slide as if the user clicked the right button. This example is not working for me.

Comment: Please **do not** pass strings to `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. It's `eval` in disguise, and every time you use `eval`, a ninja chops off a kitten's head. ☹

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setInterval( "clickRight()", 5000 );

function clickRight()
{
   $('.slide_right').trigger('click'); 
};
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.slide_right').trigger('click');
```

or

```
$('.slide_right').click();
```

Comment: .click() is what I would use, +1 for showing trigger as well.

Comment: The do the same thing, by I prefer the .trigger() as the more intuitive visual cue.

Comment: Its `trigger('click')` every time for me. Im not sure why though

Answer (score 4):

You can [trigger an event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$("element").trigger("event");
```

Bind the event to an element:

```
$("element").bind("event");
```

It does accept [normal events like `click`, ... and also custom events.](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger to force your event:

```
function clickRight(){
 $('.slide_right').trigger('click');
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "clickRight()", 5000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a name to the click function and do a setInterval like this...

```
$("#Id").click(function _clickFunction(){
  something();
};  

interval=setInterval( function{
  _clickFunction();
},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("id").click()
// "id" is the element which you want to trigger click() action
```