# How can I trigger the click event on a list element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a 3rd party web app I want to trigger click on an element in a list with jQuery automatically like a physical mouse click.

The list contains player data and these data are always different because its like an auction. Element classes are always named the same.

Selected named: `class="listFUTItem has-auction-data selected"`

A non-selected element is named: `class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"`

The list is looking like this:

[image: Transferlist click for full view]

With MutationObserver I already edited the heights of an element and if the price is below average of my database its coloured in addition style like seen here:

[image: Deal click for full view]

Now I want to auto select a deal where the Elements class matches `'[style*="background-color"]'`

I also tried adding a selected class to the element but then the side panel wont have any affect on that.

The trasnferlist HTML looks like this:

[image: HTML view]

with side panel I mean this event:

[image: gif of UI]

That's the MutationObserver Code with jQuery inside:

```
var observeTransferList = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function (node) {
        if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.matches(".has-auction-data")) {
            $(node).css("height", "37");
            $(node).removeClass('selected');

            chrome.storage.sync.get(function (items) {
                platform = items.platform;
                percentage = items.percentage;
                var playerData = getPlayerData(node, platform, percentage);


                $(node).append(playerData);
                if (playerData.colorPicked) {
                    $(node).css("backgroundColor", playerData.colorPicked); //can be "" by default, or green, yellow etc
                    //$(node).css("height", "37");
                    var price = Math.trunc(
                        parseInt(playerData.binValue.replace(/,/g, "")) / 0.949
                    );
                }


   // -------- CODE HERE -----------//
                if (node.matches('[style*="background-color"]')) { //works
                    $(node).css("height", "60"); //works
                    $(node).addClass('selected')//works
                    //$(node).click('selected'); // not working
                    //$(node).click(); // not working 
                   //$(node).trigger('click'); //notworking
                   //$(node).trigger('click', ['selected']); // not working even when adding a selected class after page load and remove old selected

                }
```

I tried a solution like:

[Difference between .click() and actually clicking a button? (javascript/jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127908/difference-between-click-and-actually-clicking-a-button-javascript-jquery)

[Trigger a click event on an inner element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632125/trigger-a-click-event-on-an-inner-element)

[executing a click function without the user clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819198/executing-a-click-function-without-the-user-clicking)
too

Somehow I need to trigger the event of the listelement which changes the side panel. Somehow the virtual click has to trigger the events bound to a real mouse click. But what am I missed out?

Answer (score 0):

Every mouse event comes with attribute `isTrusted`. This attribute is set to false if the event was generated by `element.click()` method. Therefore, the site you are talking about can implement a check that would prevent javascript browser automatization (`.click()` method).

I had a similar problem as you and the only solution that I found was to use python-browser-automatization [Selenuim for python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Selenium comes with chrome driver (simulating the entire chrome browser) which provides cookies, all the javascript API, and most important for you, it can generate MouseEvents with `isTrusted` attribute.

Comment: Every edit at the WebApp has been made by a Chrome Extension. Honestly i am not willing to rewrite everything into python or java for having a running instance.. May a AutoPixelSelector is the easiest way then